# Movie about a man and a woman accelerated in time. The rest of the world was suspended in time

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

This is a movie I saw on TV in the mid to late sixties, so I’m not sure if it was a made for TV movie or if it was out in theater in the late 50’s or early 60’s.  I only remember bits and pieces of it.  What I remember is a man and a woman accelerated in time.  The rest of the world was either suspended in time or moving very slowly.  The man I believe was either a pilot, or humanoid alien, and his plane, or spaceship, looked like it was about to crash but was suspended in time a few feet above the ground.  I’m not sure if they were trying to do something to save the world or trying to save someone, but whatever they needed to do I think they only had an hour to do it before normal time resumed again.  I also remember a scene where they were going along a street and found a boy running out in front of a truck and would most likely be hit when normal time resumed.  They used the truck’s seat belt to tie the emergency brake on so the truck would stop when normal time resumed.  I have been waiting a long time to see if it would be on TV again, but no luck.
I know it’s not much to go on, but I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Though not quite what your looking for, Barry Morse also starred in another Outer Limit's show called "Controlled Experiment" that also involved time being wound and then rewound in order to watch an incident unfold at various speeds, forward and backward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a 'The Outer Limits' episode called [The Premonition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Premonition_%28The_Outer_Limits%29) from January 1965

Per wikipedia

> Jim Darcy, the pilot of an X-15 rocket-powered research aircraft, and
>   his wife, Linda, become trapped 10 seconds ahead of their time,
>   enabling them to watch time unfold to catch up with them at the rate
>   of about one second every 30 minutes. In the time left before
>   returning to synch with normal time, they see that their daughter,
>   Janie, is about to be hit by a rolling military truck whose parking
>   brake had not been set. **Jim and Linda's inability to move objects in
>   the "real" world prevents them from resetting the truck's parking
>   brake or pulling young Janie out of danger.** Their problem is
>   aggravated as they soon learn that at the moment when time "catches
>   up" with them, they must assume the exact positions they had been in
>   five hours earlier, when this whole thing started, or they could
>   remain in that state forever.
>
> **Jim hits upon a way to save his daughter from death. He removes
>   seatbelts from his wife's car and ties them to the back wheel of the
>   menacing truck. He then ties the other end around the brake lever** so
>   that the truck's brakes will engage the moment the time warp ends. (It
>   was, by that time, moving at 10 mph.

Comment: Though not quite what your looking for, Barry Morse also starred in another Outer Limit's show called "Controlled Experiment" that also involved time being wound and then rewound in order to watch an incident unfold at various speeds, forward and backward.

Comment: @jim - You might want to repost this comment on the question, not my answer. That way it'll appear in the OPs in-box. That being said, they haven't been back in 18 months so it's unlikely they'll ever see it :-(