Old episode from the 60s in which two pilots landed at their base and realized they had somehow traveled ahead through time
Two pilots landed at their base and realized they had somehow traveled ahead through time. One pilot went home and could see that his little girl (who, along with everyone else, was in slo-mo) would get hit by a car. So he attached a rope to somehow stop the car, and to basically save the girl's life once time caught up.
Anyone remember this? Thanks!

Very likely a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73632/20774 - Outer Limits (1965) "The Premonition"

Does this answer your question? Movie about a man and a woman accelerated in time. The rest of the world was suspended in time

@RohitGupta - our meta-policy is that we only close story-id questions as duplicates when they both have accepted answers

Is this "The Premonition" (1965), S02E16 of The Outer Limits (1963–1965)...?
From Wikipedia:

Jim Darcy, the pilot of an X-15 rocket-powered research aircraft, and his wife, Linda, become trapped 10 seconds ahead of their time, enabling them to watch time unfold to catch up with them at the rate of about one second every 30 minutes. In the time left before returning to synch with normal time, they see that their daughter, Janie, is about to be hit by a rolling military truck whose parking brake had not been set. Jim and Linda's inability to move objects in the "real" world prevents them from resetting the truck's parking brake or pulling young Janie out of danger.
[...]
On discovering that he can move and manipulate items in the crashed plane and car, Jim hits upon a way to save his daughter from death. He removes seatbelts from his wife's car and ties them to the back wheel of the menacing truck. He then ties the other end around the brake lever so that the truck's brakes will engage the moment the time warp ends. (It was, by that time, moving at 10 mph.)




